# Windows Phone Live control: SignInButton - how to prevent it from connecting to internet?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, live, onedrive

`Live:SignInButton` (on Windows Phone 7) tries to connect to the internet immediately after navigating to the page with it.

Is it possible to disable this functionality? I want it to connect to the internet at the moment the user wants it. Currently it is using internet packets every time user enters application. Any workarounds are welcome too.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but I'll answer anyway. If you give "wl.offline_acces" to SignInButton it will automatically connect how ever if you don't give it user has to click to button to connect. You can use custom button if you want. You can find the code right here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh243641.aspx#signin